# how to find the middle number in python

Tags: python

Given 3 numbers, I need to find which number lies between the two others.

ie,given 3,5,2
I need 3 to be returned.

I tried to implement this by going thru all three and using if else conditions to check if each is between the other two.But this seems a naive way to do this.Is there a better way?

Comment: Which result do you expect for `[1,1,2]`?

Comment: for [1,1,2] , 1 should be taken as middle number

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put them in a list, sort them, pick the middle one.

Comment: Sven, beside being a generic answer, it is bad for the case of 3 numbers. If this kind of subroutine appears in heavy-calculations-related task, creating a list of three elements and sorting it is not the right thing even for Python. Imagine the guy next time working i.e. in c++ and creating a vector of three numbers and sorting it...

Comment: @BasicWolf: Have you benchmarked it? The difference is not that large

Comment: @Niklas B. The difference is small indeed. My concerns about the overheads of the sorted list solution and it just sounds wrong.  Have you seen this: http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes ?

Comment: @BasicWolf: No, but I'll check it out. I guess it's about how simplicity and reability usually are the most important aspects of your code.

Comment: @BasicWolf: In most cases, readability matters more than performance, and you can't beat `sorted((a, b, c))[1]` in that regard.

Answer (score 16):

```py
>>> x = [1,3,2]
>>> sorted(x)[len(x) // 2]
2
```

Answer (score 10):

The fastest obvious way for **three** numbers

```
def mean3(a, b, c):
    if a <= b <= c or c <= b <= a:
        return b
    elif b <= a <= c or c <= a <= b:
        return a
    else:
        return c
```

Comment: `mean3(3,5,2)` will give 2 instead of 3 ?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is the **median**. You can use this code below for any number of numbers:

```
import numpy
numbers = [3,5,2]
median = numpy.median(numbers)
```

for a custom solution you can visit this [page](http://codecomments.wordpress.com/2008/03/17/simple-method-to-calculate-median-in-python/).

Comment: In the case of the OP I don't think he is ready to be using something like numpy.

Comment: Not quite. The OP wants the middle number in a list. Of course, this is somewhat ambiguous for a list with even number of elements. numpy.median([3,5,2]) = 3.0 (float!). numpy.median([3,5,2,1]) = 2.5, not at all what the OP has in mind!

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
numbers = [3, 5, 2]
sorted(numbers)[1]
```

Comment: Even though this would be completely fine, id just hate to have a hard coded `1`

Answer (score 2):

This is a O(n) implementation of the median using cumulative distributions. It's faster than sorting, because sorting is O(ln(n)*n).

```
def median(data):
    frequency_distribution = {i:0 for i in data}
    for x in data:
        frequency_distribution[x] =+ 1
    cumulative_sum = 0
    for i in data:
        cumulative_sum += frequency_distribution[i]
        if (cumulative_sum > int(len(data)*0.5)):
            return i
```

Comment: smart solution to a different question though, because here we only have `3` items...

Comment: `median([8, 1, 4])` gives me 1 !!

Answer (score 1):

Check this (Suppose list already sorted):

```
def median(list):
    ceil_half_len = math.ceil((len(list)-1)/2)   # get the ceil middle element's index
    floor_half_len = math.floor((len(list)-1)/2) # get the floor middle element 's index'
    return (list[ceil_half_len] + list[floor_half_len]) / 2
```

Comment: This returns `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float`.  You need to wrap math.ceil and math.floor with int()

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for 3 numbers. First find the max and the min numbers in list. Remove them, the remainder of list is the medium. If you don't want to use the "if-else" or "sorted()" that is.

```
def mid(a,b,c):
    num = [a,b,c]
    small, big = min(num), max(num)
    num.remove(small)
    num.remove(big)
    return num[0] # return the remainder
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt using a more pythonic version

```
def median(a):
    sorted_a = sorted(a)
    if len(a) % 2 == 0:
        median = sum(sorted_a[(len(a)//2)-1:(len(a)//2)+1])/2.
    else:
        median = sorted_a[(len(a)-1)//2]

>>> x = [64630, 11735, 14216, 99233, 14470, 4978, 73429, 38120, 51135, 67060]
>>> median(x)
>>> 44627.5
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]
>>> median(y)
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to avoid sorting, you can do:

```
def find_median(x):
    return sum(x) - max(x) - min(x)
```